# What does it mean to increase volume by X decibels?

Tags: acoustics

I am trying to decipher what decibels are:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel

It seems to be a log ratio of audio amplitude multiplied by a constant. I am confused by what this means though.

If my original volume is X, what does say increasing the volume by Y decibels mean?

Does it mean `New Volume = 10 log ( Y / X )`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it right but you applied the formula backwards.  The power of the sound waves (at any given point) is formalized in Wikipedia as the following using the *bel* unit:

$$P_1 = 10^{L_B} P_0$$

A value in *bel* is 10 times the value in *decibels*

$$ L_{dB} = L_B / 10$$

You are interested in the power at a power level $X+Y$ decibels versus the power at a previous power level, $X$ decibles.  To get this ratio we will divide the power values.

$$ \frac{P_2}{P_1} = \frac{10^{X/10+Y/10} P_0}{10^{X/10} P_0} = 10^{Y/10}$$

That is to say, increasing power by $10 Y$ decibels will multiply power by 10 to the $Y$.  If you look at [loudness charts](http://www.gcaudio.com/resources/howtos/loudness.html), this sounds right.  Truck traffic (90 dB) seems about 10 times as loud as a telephone dial tone (80 dB).

Comment: $Y$ in the second equation is in bels, while in the third equation it is decibels.  This is clear because $\frac{P_2}{P_1}$ has two inconsistent expressions.

Comment: @RossMillikan I was using two different definitions of Y, this is confusing and unnecessary so I edited, put all variables in decibels now.  Thanks.